# How can I make items inside the array adapter clickable?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Basically I'm trying to make a view open with the item tapped inside the array adapter. It states that I need to use the

```
setOnItemClickListener()
```

I'm not sure where do I need to put that method as it only works with listview.

```
package com.icemalta.dylan.memorybuddy;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class NoteList extends ListActivity {

private static final int ADD_NOTE_REQUEST = 10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_list);
    loadNotes();
}

private void loadNotes() {
    // ArrayList<Note> notes = StorageHelper.loadNotes(this);
    ArrayList<Note> notes =
            new MemoryBuddyContract.MemoryBuddyDbHelper(this).getNotes();

    if (notes.size() > 0) {
        Note.notes = notes;

        ArrayAdapter notesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(

                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                Note.notes
        );
        this.setListAdapter(notesAdapter);
    }
}

public void showAddNoteView(View v) {
    Intent intAddNote = new Intent(this, AddNote.class);
    this.startActivityForResult(intAddNote, ADD_NOTE_REQUEST);
}

public void showViewNoteView(View v) {
    Intent intViewNote = new Intent(this, AddNote.class);
    this.startActivityForResult(intViewNote, ADD_NOTE_REQUEST);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ADD_NOTE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        String title = data.getStringExtra("title");
        String desc = data.getStringExtra("desc");
        String dateString = data.getStringExtra("date");

        try {

            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy H:m").parse(dateString);
            Note n = new Note(title, desc, date);

            //StorageHelper.saveNotes(this, Note.notes);
            new MemoryBuddyContract.MemoryBuddyDbHelper(this).addNote(n);

            ArrayAdapter<Note> noteAdapater = new ArrayAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    Note.notes
            );
            this.setListAdapter(noteAdapater);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: yes do that and then add a view.setOnClickListener() in the adpater

Answer (score 1):

just create custom adapter for listitem and then you can use click listener,try this way

```
public class Myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<String> data = null;
    WeatherHolder holder;

    public Myadapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> data) {
        // super(context, layoutResourceId, data, coeff);
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_cours_name);
            holder.b = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.button);
            holder.b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   System.out.println("Clicked");
                }
            });
            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (WeatherHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.b.setTag(holder);
        String name1 = data.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(name1);

        return row;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder {

        TextView name;
        ImageButton b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make custom adapter.. as

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SMSData> {

    // List context
    private final Context context;
    // List values
    private final List<SMSData> smsList;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<SMSData> smsList) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_main, smsList);
        this.context = context;
        this.smsList = smsList;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);

        TextView senderNumber = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.smsNumberText);
        senderNumber.setText(smsList.get(position).getNumber());

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

and set it as..

```
setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(context, yourlist));
```

and override the method..in activity

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        SMSData sms = (SMSData)getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sms.getBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```